# MySQL query takes too long in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, php, codeigniter

I've made this query

```
SELECT id,name,iupac_name,inchi_key,molecular_weight,molecular_formula,exact_molecular_mass
    FROM compound
    WHERE name LIKE '%quer%'
    OR iupac_name LIKE '%quer%'
    OR inchi_key LIKE '%quer%'
    OR inchi_key IN( SELECT inchi_key FROM compound_synonyms WHERE name LIKE '%quer%')
```

that took 0.3563 seconds to show result through phpmyadmin in my local machine and took 0.1117 seconds in digital ocean vps.

But the same query took 24+ minutes in another vps.

Does anyone can help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Several things make the query slow:

- Leading wildcard in `LIKE`.  (See below)
- `OR` -- One workaround is with `UNION`.
- `IN ( SELECT ... )` -- This one is version-dependent; what version is each machine running?

The first two can be alleviated by using a `FULLTEXT(name, iupac_name, inchi_key)` and `MATCH(name, iupac_name, inchi_key) AGAINST('quer*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.